# How can I set value to an HTML attribute?

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I set the value of a function to a HTML-attribute.

e.g. set attribute value to the value of foo.

```
foo () : string
{  return "bar";
}
```

Tried this without success.

```
<input type="button" value="{{foo ()}}"/>

<input type="button" [value]="foo ()"/>

<input type="button" value="foo ()"/>
```

Comment: you need to set foo as a function as a requirement? why can't you set it as a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Works Fine:
    @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <h1>Hello, {{ name }}</h1>
    <button (click)="increment()">Click {{ counter }}</button>
    <input type="button" value="{{ increment()}}"/>
    
  `,
    })
    class HomeComponent {
    counter = 0;
    name = 'Angular 2'
    
    increment() {
        return "bar";
    }
    }
```